# rpois function to each element in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of numbers and I want to apply rpois to each element of the matrix.
the matrix looks like this

```
[1,]               112                119                 222                85                  101                  99

[2,]               117                154                 205               123                 113                 133

[3,]             28708              19994               33608             21151               11579               15436

[4,]                 0                  6                  16                 0                   0                   7
```

how do I apply the rpois function to every element of the matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the matrix elements to be the lambda parameter:

```
outputMatrix <- rpois(length(inputMatrix), inputMatrix)
dim(outputMatrix) <- dim(inputMatrix)
```

Don't use `apply` as that is essentially just a loop over every element.